# Find modal number in array

Tags: java, arrays, topmost

I have array like this:

```
int[] array = { 2, 4, 6, 8, -3, 8, 2, 7, 2, 4 };
```

I want to know which number is showing the most time (in this case its 2 of course), how can i do that?

Comment: From the int[] I'd say Java.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the code below will do the trick in Java 8.

```
int[] array = { 2, 4, 6, 8, -3, 8, 2, 7, 2, 4 };
Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
      .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v.size()));
```

Prints:

```
2: 3
4: 2
8: 2
6: 1
7: 1
-3: 1
```

Comment: The `toString()` calls aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an algorithm like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
for (int n : array) {
  frequencies.put(n, frequencies.getOrDefault(n, 0) + 1); // Java 8
}

if (!frequencies.isEmpty()) {
  Integer bestMatch = null;
  Integer lastCount = null;
  for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : frequencies.entrySet()) {
    Integer count = entry.getValue(); 
    if (null == lastCount || count > lastCount) {
      bestMatch = entry.getKey(); 
      lastCount = count;
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Most frequent value: " + bestMatch + " (found " + lastCount + " times)");
}
```

- We first compute the number of times a value appear
- We select the max value in map and store the associated key.

Answer (score 0):

You could contruct a map mapping ints to their count. In Java, something like `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`. Go through the list and check if the int already is in the map. If so, add 1 to its count, else initialize it to 1. Afterwards, go back through the map and find the number with the highest count.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a frequency distribution and iterate through the array. As you're using integers this makes it easy as they can be used as the key directly.

```
HashTable frequencyDistribution = new HashTable();
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    int key = array[i];
    if( !frequencyDistribution.containsKey( key ) ) frequencyDistribution.add( key, 0 );
    frequencyDistribution[ key ]++;
}
int modeKey;
int modeCnt = int.MIN;
foreach(int key in frequencyDistribution.keys) {
    int cnt = frequencyDistribution[key];
    if( cnt > modeCnt ) modeKey = key;
}
print("Most frequent is: {0} as it appears {1} times.", modeKey, modeCnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bucket sort's bucket filling step and then linearly scan all the buckets to get the most frequently appearing number (you know how to get the maximum number in an array, right?). The underlying data structure does NOT have to be an array (which is the fastest), you can use anything that has key -> value mechanism because for BIG range, an array might not be possible due to memory constraint, with the expense of slower running time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort them first
2. Now go in a loop and see if the number is repeated
3. If so count number of times it got repeated and store its details.
4. Do the same thing in through out the loop.  If any other number has more counts just replace the details you stored with new number.  You can store details like number and count in a separate variable.